# How to stop redirecting after `drop` event?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

After dropping a file into a `div` in Firefox, the webpage will be redirected to this file. I tried to stop this propagation using jQuery's `e.preventDefault()` in `drop` handler, and failed.

See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mKtn2/3/), dropping a file into `#test` won't redirect the webpage, but dropping into `#test1` will, I want to know why. Should I always bind handlers to `dragenter`, `dragover`, `dragleave` and `drop` to prevent propagation after `drop`?

update:

I found some tips on [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/):

> To tell the browser we can drop in this element, all we have to do is
>   cancel the dragover event. However, since IE behaves differently, we
>   need to do the same thing for the dragenter event.

And Mozilla [claims](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Specifying_Drop_Targets):

> A listener for the `dragenter` and `dragover` events are used to
>   indicate valid drop targets, that is, places where dragged items may
>   be dropped.

But I test [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mKtn2/7/) on firefox, `#test` works and `#test1` doesn't, seems Mozilla made a mistake, and html5doctor is right: Firefox needs `dragover` only to make `drop` work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `ondragover` event needs to be canceled in **Google Chrome** and **Safari** to allow firing the `ondrop` event.

Comment: Ahh, found one. 'A listener for the dragenter and dragover events are used to indicate valid drop targets' https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#Specifying_Drop_Targets . But my demo works without `dragenter`: http://jsfiddle.net/mKtn2/6/

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it wasn't just enough to cancel onDragOver, but I also had to cancel onDragDrop and onDragLeave.  Below, I'm showing logging indicating what behavior the user is doing :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var handledragleave = function handleDragLeave(e) {
            console.log("Floating away.  Do code here when float away happens.");
            return this.cancelDefaultBehavior(e);
    }

    var handledragdrop = function handleDrop(e) {
            console.log("Dropping.  Do code here when drop happens.");
            return this.cancelDefaultBehavior(e);
    }

    var handledragover = function handleDragOver(e) {
            console.log("Floating over.  Do code here when float over happens.");
            return this.cancelDefaultBehavior(e);
    }

    cancelDefaultBehavior(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            return false;
    }

$('.your-element-being-dragged-to')
    .on('DragLeave', handledragleave)
    .on('DragDrop', handledragdrop)
    .on('DragOver', handledragover);

</script>
```

And then your element...

```
<p class="your-element-being-dragged-to">Drag something here!</p>
```