# Drop event doesn't stop in FF

Tags: html, preventdefault

Works in chrome, but not in Firefox, version 16.0.2. Not even gonna bother with IE.
When I drag a file from desktop to FF, drop it there, it's supposed to stop the default action (open file), but it doesn't. Obviously something very easy, just can't see it, please help. This works in chrome, but not in FF:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    Why ??
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).bind('drop', docDrop);

    function docDrop(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where are you dropping, over the text 'Why ??' or somewhere else on the page?

Comment: There will be a div, where i will drop it, but right now I'm trying to get it to work with the browser document. Don't look at the body, it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. If that stops the propagation then it means that you have bound the `drop` event multiple times. You may want to consider an `unbind` before or after the event is completed.

Comment: Tried e.stopImmediatePropagation(), nothing. Even the simple code I gave in the first post doesn't work, so no multiple binds.

Answer (score 0):

Right, got it to work myself.
So here's the solution for future googlers:

Firefox needs also 'dragover' event defined, if you want the 'drop' event to work. So here's code that works:

```
$(document).bind('dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
$(document).bind('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

also another topic on the subject:
[How to stop redirecting after `drop` event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938319/how-to-stop-redirecting-after-drop-event)