# jQuery Drag and Drop Changes My URL - Return False Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I can't figure out why my drag and drop code is making my url change.  I have tried adding in return false statements but every time I drop an element the url changes to the root localhost.

```
$(".trek_trip_container .activity_link").draggable({
"snapMode": "inner",
"revert": function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data("uiDraggable").originalPosition = {
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    };

    $(this).draggable("option", "axis", false);

    // return boolean
    return !event;
    // that evaluate like this:
    // return event !== false ? false : true;
},
"drag": function(event, ui) {
    var top_position = 1632 - (parseInt($(this).css("top")) + parseInt($(this).parent().css("top"))),
        time = $(".time_holder").html().trim();

    $(".trek_slider").slider("value", top_position);
    $(this).find(".schedule").html(time);

    return false;
}
});

$(".trek_slider_containment").droppable({
"tolerance": "fit",
"over": function(event,
    ui) {
    var dropped_el = $(ui.draggable).parent();

    $(".trek_slider_containment").append(dropped_el);

    $(ui.draggable).find(".activity_caret").show();
    $(ui.draggable).find("i").show();
    $(ui.draggable).addClass("added_to_timeline");

    $(ui.draggable).draggable("option", "axis", "y");
    $(ui.draggable).draggable("option", "revert", false);

    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Changing the URL from what to what?

Answer (score 0):

Is this question the same ?

[How to stop redirecting after `drop` event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938319/how-to-stop-redirecting-after-drop-event)

You can also try to add :

```
e.preventDefault();
```

On the drop event you dont wan't to act like a redirection.